# How to get posts with few conditions rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Users can add posts, Posts are categorized
When I'm  in user's profile I can see only his posts

I want to see this user's posts from chosen category, how to do this?
How to view posts of this user from chosen category?

This is link to category

```
link_to category.name, posts_path(category: category.name, user_id: current_user), class:"category"
```

below is my method

```
def my_things   
    if params[:category].blank?
        @posts = Post.where(user_id: current_user).order("created_at DESC")
    else
        @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
        @posts = Post.where(category_id: @category_id).order('created_at DESC')
    end 
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the query and make it more readable, and separate the shared stuff from the specific stuff.

I've replaced `@category_id` with `@category` cause it's more useful, if you won't use it at all in the views then just make it a local variable, without the `@`

```
def my_things
  @posts = Post.where(user_id: current_user).order(created_at: :desc)
  unless params[:category].blank?
    @category = Category.find_by(name: params[:category])
    @posts = @posts.where(category: @category)
  end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I got it

category link:

```
link_to category.name, my_things_posts_path(category: category.name, user_id: current_user), class:"category"
```

method:

```
def my_things   
    if params[:category].blank?
        @posts = Post.where(user_id: current_user).order("created_at DESC")
    else
        @category_id = Category.find_by(name: params[:category]).id
        @posts = Post.where(category_id: @category_id, user_id: current_user)
    end 
end
```